# How do I deal with acne on my back?

Tags: dermatology, acne

I have a lot of acne on my back and some always burst and bleed. I find blood on the back of my shirt almost every day.

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotal evidence is not credible. Although other peoples' answers (on this question and elsewhere) may have worked for them, the fact is everyone is different and will react differently to different home remedies and/or medications/diets.

Acne is studied by many and there is great controversy over root causes and cures. Some people spend their entire life trying to find a solution, whether they're diets, pills, creams, home remedies, etc...

The best advice I have is to **see a dermatologist**. There is no one with more experience than them, and only they will truly be able to tell what your issue is.

Comment: If your only answer is "See a doctor", then instead of answering you should vote to close as being off topic.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue: bacne and this is the advice I got from a doctor. This is a multi-pronged approach, one part is changing your diet.

1. Do not expect a pill to solve all your problems. Take personal responsibility for changing your habits.
2. Avoid all processed sugar. For the most part this is impossible for most people. But I still give the advice and it should still be a goal. Sugar is not good for you in the quantities people eat today because there is so much hidden sugar.
3. Change your shirt every day. Do not wear it twice. Wear it once then wash it.
4. Get a OTC soap at the pharmacy/chemist that has 10% benzoyl peroxide. From my doctor. 
   Wash your back with that every day.
5. Avoid eating greasy fried foods. Some people find this helps.
6. Eat more fiber. It's critical to support the good bacteria in your gut and overall balance of the body. Google "microbiota" in your gut.

   - [Benzoyl Peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzoyl_peroxide#Acne_treatment) from Wikipedia.
   - [WebMD link](http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/acne/tc/acne-treatment-with-benzoyl-peroxide-topic-overview)
   - [541,000 links from a Bing search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=acne+treatment+benzoyl+peroxide&qs=AS&pq=acne+treatment+ben&sc=8-18&sp=1&cvid=15B7810AA6734453846F92EDAE06AB24&FORM=QBLH&ghc=1)

Comment: This may or may not be good advice, do you have any references other than "My doctor said"?

Comment: See my edits above.